# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ORB'

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

when I run my python code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('/home/shar/home.jpg',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('/home/shar/home2.jpg',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10], flags=2)

plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ORB'
```

I am using python3 and opencv3

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found this also.  I checked the actual contents of the `cv2` module and found `ORB_create()` rather than `ORB()`

Use the line

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
```

instead of `orb = cv2.ORB()` and it will work.

Verified on Python 3.4, OpenCV 3 on Windows, using the OpenCV test data set `box.png` and `box_in_scene.png` with the following results.  ***Note*** you have to put in `None` for `outImg` in the line `img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10], flags=2)` also - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631995/838992) to your other question.

[image: box scene output]

Comment: Which is it, `create_ORB()` or `ORB_create()`? You use one in your text but the other in your code.

Comment: Sorry - typo. @berak kindly edited one instance, but missed the other.  It was late here when I typed it is my only excuse :)  Both corrected to `ORB_create()`

Comment: can i match the feature on real time ?