# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in drawKeypoints,

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I'm learning `SIFT algorithm` in order to compare images and detect common objects.
I'm beginning in this domain and I'm writing a little script to get Keypoints in firstime but I get an error.

**My script :**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')          # trainImage
gray = cv2.imread('test.jpg',1)

# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
img = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,None)

cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
```

I want to display the gray picture with all keypoints, but I get the following error :

```
(cv) valentin@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python image.py 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in drawKeypoints, file /home/valentin/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 113
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 13, in <module>
    img = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,None)
cv2.error: /home/valentin/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:113: error: (-215) !outImage.empty() in function drawKeypoints
```

I read this post : [TypeError: Required argument 'outImg' (pos 6) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631352/typeerror-required-argument-outimg-pos-6-not-found)

So I added `None` inside `drawKeypoints` but impossible to get a good result.

Do you have an idea ?

I'm working on `Python 2.7` and `OpenCV 3.1`

Thank you ;)

**EDIT :**

If I just write this some lines :

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/valentin/Bureau/ville.jpg')        
gray = cv2.imread('ville.jpg',0)
cv2.imwrite('test_gray.jpg',gray)

plt.imshow(img), plt.show()
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Comment: Please check if the images you are reading in are really jpg's and not png's? Furthermore, if you want to read in an image as gray-scale, the parameter should be 0 not 1 as you specified it.

Comment: @KevinKatzke My images are really in jpeg's format. The probleme is always with the `drawKeypoints function`

Comment: I'm sure that the problem lies in opencv not being able to load the gray image. Try to add `cv2.imwrite('test_gray.jpg',gray)` right after you load the gray image to see if the loading really works.

Comment: I have always the same error : `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!outImage.empty()) in drawKeypoints, file /home/valentinjungbluth/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp, line 113
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 17, in <module>
    img = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,img)
cv2.error: /home/valentinjungbluth/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp:113: error: (-215) !outImage.empty() in function drawKeypoints`

Possible a bad openCV installation ? But it's strange

Comment: I added an edit part in my question