# ImportError: No module named cv2

Tags: python, windows, opencv

```
import numpy as np

import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg',0)

orb = cv2.ORB()

kp = orb.detect(img,None)

kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)


img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2),plt.show()
```

In here, I have installed numpy and opencv in my windows operating system. But i can't find out the proper way to add cv2 module.

Comment: @jlnabais The OP mentions installing OpenCV on Windows, not Ubuntu, so if it is a duplicate question, then not that one.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV precisely? From binaries or source? Did you follow these installation instructions https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#install-opencv-python-in-windows ?

Comment: on windows - it's often worth trying installing prebuilt wheels from Gohlke's excellent site - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv.  i think that's how I got my OpenCV on windows (it's ages since I installed it - sorry I can't recall details)

Comment: Use the prebuilt windows packages [distributed by Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).  I have just done a clean install of Python 3.5 on Windows and installed numpy, matplotlib and OpenCV from that repository.  It works out of the box - no module errors as you experience. Note that you might be trying to code according an old version of the open CV API.  In particular - you might need to use `cv.ORB_create()` tather that `cv.ORB()` (see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31632268/838992)) and you might need other parameters for `drawKeypoints()`

Answer (score 17):

The fastest and cleanest way is to run `pip`. It's a clean convenient tool for Python packages.

Just run:

`pip install opencv-python` or `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install opencv-python`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install OpenCV on Windows is to simply copy the `cv2.pyd` file into Python's `site-packages` directory (e.g. `C:\python27\Lib\site-packages`).

To get the `cv2.pyd` file, download and extract the latest version of the OpenCV installation executable from http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/ and browse the extracted folder to find the file in the relevant `build` directory (e.g. `build\python\x86\2.7`).

Comment: I've also copy cv2.pyd file into site-packages, but now there  occurring a new  error.
"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." @figs

Comment: That could be related to something else, e.g. importing `numpy` or `matplotlib`. Try a much simpler script that only imports `cv2`. Also check out this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221427/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found-python